# Does iPhone support adding custom properties to Address Book records?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, synchronization, addressbook

Does anyone know if iPhone (i.e. Cocoa Touch) lets you create custom properties?

I've used it with the mac before (where it works beautifully) and would like to use this technology for an iPhone app that syncs with an app on the mac through the Address Book (using MobileMe). If I can't use custom properties, however, I'll have to abandon this strategy.

For the mac, it's relatively easy: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/
Conceptual/AddressBook/Tasks/AddingProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001026-BABHHIHC

Does anyone know if this is possible on the iPhone?

Cheers,

Gregor,
Sweden

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nope, sorry, the AddressBook framework on the iPhone is woefully lacking in this regard. Also, no "me" card.